# store procedure sql server 2008 in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter

I was trying every possibilities, but still empty the output in codeigniter .. 
I execute all query in SQL Server and it not working for me

```
 sp_detail_report XX64,'2018-01-01','2018-02-01',0,1

 EXEC sp_detail_report XX64,'2018-01-01','2018-02-01',0,1

 EXECUTE sp_detail_report XX64,'2018-01-01','2018-02-01',0,1

EXEC sp_detail_report @appl = 'XX64',@StartDate = '2018-01-01',@EndDate = '2018-02-01',@List = 0,@State = 1

sp_detail_report {XX64},{'2018-01-01'},{'2018-02-01'},{0},{1}
```

this controller

```
public function detail_report_sp()
{
    $query = $this->Report_model->tbl_detail_report_sp2();

    $exec =  $query->result();      
    var_dump($exec);
    print_r($exec);
}
```

this is my model

```
public function tbl_detail_report_sp2()
{
    $otherdb = $this->load->database('otherdb', TRUE);
    $data =  " EXEC sp_detail_report XX64,'2018-01-01','2018-02-01',0,1; ";
    $sql = $otherdb->query($data);
    return $sql;    
}
```

Output error always

```
Message: Call to a member function result_array() on boolean
```

or

```
    object(CI_DB_sqlsrv_result)[21]
  public 'scrollable' => string 'buffered' (length=8)
  public 'conn_id' => resource(49, SQL Server Connection)
  public 'result_id' => resource(51, SQL Server Statement)
  public 'result_array' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'result_object' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'custom_result_object' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  public 'current_row' => int 0
  public 'num_rows' => null
  public 'row_data' => null
Array ( )
```

always empty.

May you know the solution. thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

SOLVE.

I fixed in store procedure

I put SET NOCOUNT ON;

in every after BEGIN

```
BEGIN 

SET NOCOUNT ON
```